# How to move a button to the right hand of a <select> form

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, button

How do I get the "Go" button directly to the right hand of the select form instead of blow it?

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <form role="form" method="POST">
        <select class="form-control" name="per_page" required>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>15</option>
            <option>20</option>
            <option>50</option>
            <option>100</option>
        </select>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="per_page" value="Go">Go</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

(Here is a link to jsfiddle for a live version of it: http://jsfiddle.net/276vq/)

Comment: search for groups on form on bootstrap docs.

Answer (score 0):

Comment line in bootstrap css where width of class "col-xs-2" is set to 
width: 16.66666667%; because these to cannot fit together if this div is only this wide. Also, put on this select.form-control display inline, and it's width shouldn't be 100%, because in that case button will go under. Or do this in your own css (overwrite these properties in your own css).

You can also change class of div to `col-xs-5`, and add this to your css:

```
.form-control {
    display:inline;
    width:100px;
}
```